# Carrierwave - Save to S3 as an independent action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

My users store an external image URL (http://their-site.com/photo.jpg) in - for example - `@user.external_image`. I'm trying to write a method for the User class that takes that URL and saves it to S3 using Carrierwave.

So on the above `@user`, I'd like to run `@user.save_to_s3` and have it "upload" the image to S3. I've tried to do this by mounting an uploader on `:s3_image` to the User class and writing the following method:

```
def save_to_s3
  self.remote_s3_image_url = self.external_image
  save
end
```

But I get the following error when I call that method on a `@user` record:

"ArgumentError: Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key"

So it's getting close, but it's not retrieving my S3 credentials - even though they're set. I'd appreciate any thoughts or suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be unrelated to Carrierwave or Fog. It was an oversight on my part that the ENV variables which I'd set (in my app's `.env` file) were not being loaded into the bootstrapped Rails environment (e.g. rails console). Once I added http://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv (which solves precisely that issue) to my bundle, the `save_to_s3` method worked.

Comment: Can you show clearly how you solved the problem. I already had a carrierwave.rb in initializer folder but it still doesn't read the aws_key